# How to share a Facebook photo by /feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

How can I share a Facebook fanpage's photo, like the `/links` method.

And no, I can't use `/links` method, because I want to share it on my friend's wall.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish a photo to some wall you should use USER_ID/photos or ALBUM_ID/photos .. that's what I learn from the official docs:

> In order to publish a photo to a user’s album, you must have the
>   publish_stream permission. With that granted, you can upload a photo
>   by issuing an HTTP POST request with the photo content and an optional
>   description to one these to Graph API connections:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/photos - The photo will be
>   published to an album created for your app. We automatically create an
>   album for your app if it does not already exist. All photos uploaded
>   this way will then be added to this same album.
>   https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID/photos - The photo will be
>   published to a specific, existing photo album, represented by the
>   ALBUM_ID.

EDIT: you can visit this for more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/